# HELP me to find the value of Re(z)+Im(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

z is complex .

$z=(-1+i)^{2008}+(1+i)^{2008}$,

the value of Re(z)+Im(z)=...

Comment: Update the exponent! We are in 2013.

Comment: this question from my teacher, not me :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$z=(-1+i)^{2008}+(1+i)^{2008}=(\sqrt2e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}})^{2008}+(\sqrt2e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})^{2008}=$$$$=\sqrt2^{2008}+\sqrt2^{2008}=2^{1005}$$

Comment: :ok, thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

$$-1+i=\sqrt[2]2\,e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}\;,\;\;\;1+i=\sqrt[2]2\,e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\Longrightarrow\;$$

$$\Longrightarrow(-1+1)^{2008}+(1+i)^{2008}=2^{1004}\left(e^{1512\pi i}+e^{502\pi i}\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: ok, thanks :))...